# What is meant by "+srv" in the mongoDb connection string

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am new to MongoDB and just encountered two types of connection string.

1. mongodb://[username:password@]host1[:port1][,host2[:port2],...[,hostN[:portN]]][/[database][?options]]
2. mongodb+srv://[username:password@]host[/[database][?options]]

I know about the 1st one. But unfamiliar with the (+srv) in the 2nd.

```
   let connectionUrl;
      if (username && password)
        connectionUrl = `mongodb://${username}:${password}@${host}:${
          port || 27017
        }/${databaseName}`;
      else
        connectionUrl = `mongodb://${host}:${
          port || 27017
        }/${databaseName}`;
      console.log(connectionUrl, "connectionUrlconnectionUrl");
      let connection = await mongoose.createConnection(connectionUrl, {
        useNewUrlParser: true,
      });
      return connection;
```

Now the problem user can enter username, password, hostname, etc...

But is there any way to know when to add  ***(+srv)*** because I was trying with localhost and with MongoDB atlas.
Atlas works fine with +srv but in the case of localhost, it's throwing an error.

Comment: check here https://developer.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/mongodb-or-mongodb-srv/1654

Comment: See [Connection String URI - formats](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/index.html#connection-string-formats).

Answer (score 26, accepted):

in MongoDB 3.6 is introduced the concept of a [seed list](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/#dns-seedlist-connection-format) that is specified using DNS records, specifically [SRV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SRV_record) and [TXT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TXT_record) records. You will recall from using replica sets with MongoDB that the client must specify at least one replica set member (and may specify several of them) when connecting. This allows a client to connect to a replica set even if one of the nodes that the client specifies is unavailable

You can see an example of this URL on a 2.2.12 or later connection string

[image]

Note that without the SRV record configuration we must list several nodes (in the case of Atlas we always include all the cluster members, though this is not required). We also have to specify the ssl and replicaSet options

With the 3.4 or earlier driver, we have to specify all the options on the command line using the [MongoDB URI syntax](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/).

The use of SRV records eliminates the requirement for every client to pass in a complete set of state information for the cluster. Instead, a single SRV record identifies all the nodes associated with the cluster (and their port numbers) and an associated TXT record defines the options for the URI.

[image]

check the **[Reference](https://developer.mongodb.com/article/srv-connection-strings/)**

Answer (score 6):

In MongoDB 3.6, they introduced the concept of a seed list that is specified using DNS records, specifically SRV and TXT records.

This allows a client to connect to a replica set even if one of the nodes that the client specifies is unavailable.

Answer (score 6):

If you wonder how to get the details yourself, assuming that your host would be foo.example.com

```
host -t SRV _mongodb._tcp.foo.example.com
host -t TXT foo.example.com
```

Answer (score 3):

All the above answers specify SRV and TXT records in context of mongo conn string correctly!! Just want to add if we need to see these SRV or TXT records we can use below commands(Windws cmd i have used):

For SRV records:    `nslookup -q=SRV _mongodb._tcp.cluster0.9gztv.mongodb.net`

Above command will give you result like

```
Non-authoritative answer:
_mongodb._tcp.cluster0.9gztv.mongodb.net        SRV service location:
          priority       = 0
          weight         = 0
          port           = 27017
          svr hostname   = cluster0-shard-00-00.9gztv.mongodb.net
_mongodb._tcp.cluster0.9gztv.mongodb.net        SRV service location:
          priority       = 0
          weight         = 0
          port           = 27017
          svr hostname   = cluster0-shard-00-01.9gztv.mongodb.net
_mongodb._tcp.cluster0.9gztv.mongodb.net        SRV service location:
          priority       = 0
          weight         = 0
          port           = 27017
          svr hostname   = cluster0-shard-00-02.9gztv.mongodb.net
```

You can see the svr hostname field have 3 different sever names which are part of the replica set. Important thing is to add _mongodb._tcp as prefix.

Similarly `nslookup -q=TXT cluster0.9gztv.mongodb.net`
Will give you result as below.

```
Non-authoritative answer:
cluster0.9gztv.mongodb.net      text =

        "authSource=admin&replicaSet=atlas-uovfn7-shard-0"
```

So driver queries SRV records for the host name in connection string and then TXT record and combines them to connect to cluster.

http://pauldone.blogspot.com/2019/12/tips-for-atlas-connectivity.html